# Typesetting "||" with Latex

Tags: tex-general

I use "||" in some code listings and in normal text but it is not printed in either. How can I typeset "||" using Latex? I have tried escaping with "\" but it did not work.

Comment: Try: \usepackage{amssymb}  \parallel \shortparallel  \textbardbl  \textbar\textbar

Comment: it's not entirely clear what use you're putting this to.  `$\Vert$` is one possibility -- it requires a math context.

Comment: In many programming languages "||" denotes the logical-or operator. See, for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Logical_operators

Comment: Please, add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For text mode you need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. In math mode you can use `\vert`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Text mode ||

Math mode \(\vert \vert\)
\end{document}
```

[image]